# Bind and unbind toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bind

I have a circle which on clicked should display a close button on top.and when that close button is clicked it should hide and just display the circle.

I should be able to do that operation again and again.

```
<div class="circle"><div class="close"></div></div>​
```

Css:

```
.circle
    {
        background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Blue_circle_logo.svg/100px-Blue_circle_logo.svg.png");
        height: 100px;
        width:100px;        
    }
.circle .close
    {   display:none;
        position:relative;
        background: url("http://www.dlf-data.org.uk/images/icons/close-icon.png");
        height: 30px;
        width:30px;   
        float: right;

    }
```

​

JS:

```
$(".circle").click(function() {


$(".close").fadeIn();
$(".circle").unbind("click");
});

$(".close").click(function() {


$(".close").fadeOut();
$(".circle").bind("click");

});​
```

Here is the fiddle !! which does what i want but doesnt allow the second click!!
http://jsfiddle.net/RaExx/1/

Comment: `$(".circle").bind("click");`... you have to pass an even handler as second argument to `.bind`. If you don't tell jQuery what to bind, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".circle").click(function() {
    $(".close").fadeIn();
});

$(".close").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".close").fadeOut();
});​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RaExx/2/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your attempt to re-bind the click on circle does not tell what functionatiy to bind to it. You just say "bind a click event" whithout saying what functionality to execute. What you can do is to declare the circle click event handler first, and then you can bind it multiple times.

```
//Declare the event handler to use
var circleClick = function() {
  $(".close").fadeIn();
  $(".circle").unbind("click");
};

//Initital binding to circle click
$(".circle").click(circleClick);

//Bind close click
$(".close").click(function() {
  $(".close").fadeOut();
  //Re-binding to circle click
  $(".circle").click(circleClick);
});​
```

Note:
Using bind method to bind the event requires 2 parameters: name of event, and the event handler.

In stead of:

```
$(".circle").click(circleClick);
```

You could use:

```
$(".circle").bind("click", circleClick);
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery the .bind() event is cumbersome. It is recommended to use the .on() event instead.

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Try it like this

```
$(".circle").on("click", function() {
  $(".close").fadeIn();
});

$(".close").on("click", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(".close").fadeOut();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RaExx/4/

Comment: Cumbersome? The interface of `.bind` is basically a subset of `.on`. If any, `.on` is more cumbersome because it allows more things to do ;)